Is it ethical to make money off your own lecture notes, lectures, or technical reports?
Recently, a non-tenured professor was fired by a small regional university. While several reasons were given, I find the main reasons questionable and want to check them against generally accepted norms:

The professor published his own lecture notes online, and at the bottom of each page, there was a "Buy me a coffee" link that allowed users to donate money directly to him. This link only appeared on the notes he made available through his professional website hosted on GitHub. He also had a version uploaded to the university's e-learning system, where students could download the PDF version without seeing the donation link.
The professor published YouTube videos in which he read his own lectures with some animations and illustrations. He monetized these videos and received profit.
The professor published several technical reports that summarized long and technical papers, as well as famous but complicated experiments, in a form that was understandable for students. These were also published on his professional site with the "Buy me a coffee" link.

Over the last few years, the professor made a small amount of money through these three sources. The university ruled that this broke the ethical code, even though there were no explicit clauses in the faculty handbook addressing these actions.
My question is: Regardless of the university's perspective, do any of these actions break the generally accepted ethical code?

Related question: Is it ethical to profit by having my students buy my textbook?

@NateEldredge, The professor in question did not sell any of these to his students. His students gets note and lectures without directly paying him. Presumedly, people outside his university donated.

I know the case is different.  I only said the question was related.

I wonder if any of his current (or future) students found the professional website and 'donated' money.

It's pretty SOP that a professor writes a (super-expensive) textbook and makes it (or even a specific fresh new edition that's near-indistinguishable from previous) obligatory for their course. THAT is unethical but normal.

@user3445853, agreed, but a simple solution is to return any royalty they earn (per copy) to students and let them know it is available. Professors don't set the price of those super expensive books and may consider them to be essential (new exercises, updated material, etc). And, most professors don't teach enough students that those royalties (maybe $5 per copy, and taxed) will make them wealthy. Only general sales to others can.

@mkennedy, The "Buy me a coffee" donations are unlikely to come from current students, as there is no significant increase during the semesters when he teaches those particular courses. Instead, there appears to be a constant stream of small donations, seemingly unrelated to his teaching assignments. As for "future" students, who can say.

In Germany the Professor would have to get permission for a side business, making this not an ethical but a contractual question.

@DonQuiKong I suspect that's true everywhere. Is this ethical? Almost certainly. But it may still be against the contract the guy signed with this "small regional college", and hence a fireable offence.

@user3445853 In my experience with professors who have done this, they generally make the text available for their own students, gratis.  For example, my phd advisor had a hidden directory of books on his university website for his students (books he has authored or coauthored).  Also, in my experience, the authors of these texts are not really trying to make a buck, and would prefer that their books were cheaper---but they don't set the prices.  There are exceptions, but as a general rule, no one is trying to get rich writing textbooks.

On a completely different note, there is also the possibility that the "ethical violation" was pretextual---it is possible that there is some other problem with the instructor which has not been made public (e.g. they've been sexually harassing undergraduates), and the side business provided a pretext for firing this instructor without potentially damaging the reputation of the institution.  One would have to be somewhat conspiracy-minded to buy into this exact set of circumstances, but it is very possible that the public record is not everything.

My view is that there was no ethical violation, absent contractual obligations made clear to the professor. There was no coercion of students to contribute, which would be a different matter.
There seems to be an active attempt, separating the sources, to avoid coercion and conflicts of interest, hence avoiding ethical issues.
Had the university claimed ownership of all IP through contract then it would be a different matter as well.
Professors write books and sell them. When bought by others than their own students there are no ethical issues. There are solutions here when the professor requires their own books, such as returning the value of any royalty to the student in exchange for the receipt. Then the professor, again, isn't coercing the student to their own benefit. The situation for other IP is the same as long as you haven't given up your rights.
Actually, the "cuppa coffee" sounds like a good idea.
Perhaps a lawyer should be consulted to find a way to avoid damage to one's reputation from being fired for "ethical violations" that aren't. Maybe not reinstatement, but an acceptable letter of recommendation from a dean, or such.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@NuclearHoagie: I think the distinction is clear — imagine the professor has a side gig as a bartender or valet, it would be expected  to accept the tip. The tip isn’t being solicited in a context where the student has to go there, has to have the professor do something and there is or could be an undercurrent of “unless you want to fail this class”.  A tip for a prompt decision as to whether the class can be dropped is borderline extortion at best.  Contrast that with the YouTube monetization where the “tip” is anonymous and amounts to a fraction of a penny through watching an add…

This sounds petty and small-minded on the part of the university. As @Buffy pointed out, it’s common for professors to make small amounts of money from royalties on textbooks they’ve written. It's also less common, but also not terribly uncommon, for professors to make even large amounts of money (comparable to or exceeding their university salaries), from writing successful textbooks or from consulting gigs that often leverage the professor's reputation as an academic and benefit indirectly from the professor's ties to the university that employs him or her.
Considering these well-established norms in the US, it's hard to swallow the idea that a discreet "buy me a coffee" link posted alongside the professor's lecture notes, and similar small-scale educational initiatives with a monetization element (YouTube videos etc), constitute an ethical violation. The amounts of money these efforts yield are surely orders of magnitude smaller than the amounts of money many professors legitimately earn through textbook writing and other side enterprises that are tangential to their normal university work. And I see no real conflict of interest of any sort here. What is the university worried about? That the professor will be incentivized by all the coffee money donations to put in too much time into writing high quality lecture notes?
Seriously, this attitude seems very shortsighted. With these sorts of policies, the "small regional university" is virtually guaranteed to remain small and regional.

I’ve known one professor at a top university who was a millionaire from a successful book. Back when a million was real money.

The big factor is that students aren't pressured into paying. The fact that there is no donation link on the internal site, and it's only on the public-facing site where non-students can download it (and donation is optional even there) shows clearly that there is not even a hint of expectation from students to pay. As a contrast, I know of a case from a country with higher academic corruption, where a book report was mandatory for passing an exam, the book had to be personally ordered through the professor, and you'd fail the exam if you used a borrowed book instead of buying it.

@vsz agreed. A big reason for my assessment that this is not unethical behavior is that OP's description makes it seem like the professor has taken very sensible and thoughtful steps to avoid both the appearance of impropriety and actual impropriety.

I wonder if this was the actual reason the firing, or just a pretext.

It depends on how it was done, and we've been offered few of the relevant details.
There are scenarios that are covered by the description that clearly fall into the "don't do this" category, most of which would put the students in a situation where they feel like they need to purchase the prof's products (above and beyond a simple textbook).
So, if the "official" course material is pointing to a set of shadow course material that can generate a revenue trickle for the prof, yeah, I'd say that's not right.
Schools pay people to teach, and one's students should not be considered or treated like an advertising demographic.  All the material the students see should not have any shareware, volunteer-ware, fees that go to the prof appearing in them, as the students have already paid for the prof to be teaching them.
I have much fewer problems, if any, to the prof making the materials available to people who have not already paid to be taught -- though the university can certainly make the claim that they hold copyright if the material was developed as "work for hire", so this can get sticky.

though the university can certainly make the claim that they hold copyright if the material was developed as "work for hire":  I think that’s a pretty misleading statement. What you are saying applies also to the papers and books that academics write. And yet, in the US at least, it is generally accepted that professors hold the copyright on the material they create. Maybe universities could lay claim to it (that’s also debatable but I won’t get into the legal issues), but they don’t, and most have explicit policies stating that professors remain in control of their copyrighted material.

Also, while it’s true that students have paid to be taught, they have not paid for teaching materials, and again, there’s a norm in the US that students need to buy their own textbooks and that that’s not included with the tuition fee. Given that norm, it’s not clear to me that ethically it’s problematic to (for example) teach a course where you use your own textbook that students have to buy. And that’s not even what the professor in the question is doing - I do think the description in the question gives us enough information to determine that the behavior is not unethical.

@DanRomik -- I started an email conversation with my US University Counsel on just this issue, and they very clearly let me know that this university considers (or at least considered at the time) teaching materials to be works for hire.  I believe this is currently under review, but it's certainly where we were about 5 years ago.  Of course, this, like any other legal issue, can be contested in court should one have the resources to do so.

Further, this issue came up in the coursework I was taking on developing online coursework from our school of Education, and the expert on pedagogy who was teaching this course considers this a matter of contention

The actual quote from my email train with Counsel is "Hi Scott, if the work was produced by you as an employee (as faculty, researcher, staff, or doctoral student, etc.) as part of your University responsibilities and/or used substantial University resources to produce, then the work is considered Work for Hire under XX [name removed for a bit of privacy] policy. "

I never said it was wrong to require students to use your textbook.  Student do need to buy reading materials to support a course, and if the prof's textbook meets the need, fine.  What I'm saying is wrong is using your students as a captive audience to constantly advertise your revenue stream.  Of course, we have no way of knowing if this is or isn't the situation existing in this question, but it's certainly a possibility.

Okay, thanks for the clarification. Always interesting to hear how different institutions approach these sorts of issues.

@ScottSeidman  From AAUP "_it has been the prevailing academic practice to treat the faculty member as the copyright owner of works that are created independently and at the faculty member’s own initiative for traditional academic purposes. Examples include class notes and syllabi; books and articles; ... This practice has been followed for the most part, regardless of the physical medi­um in which these “traditional academic works” appear; that is, whether on paper or in audiovi­sual or electronic form."

@ScottSeidman, to clarify, students receive "clean" copies of the notes and technical reports that do not include donation links. YouTube videos are a different matter; students are not required to watch them and are not informed about their existence.

@timmy, yes, that's AAUP summary of "prevailing" policy, but if it were in place everywhere, they wouldn't need to use "prevailing".  The policy statement, which doesn't bind anyone, is at aaup.org/report/statement-copyright  -- but see the section on "Unilateral Institutional Policies".

@ScottSeidman,The section on "Unilateral Institutional Policies" is saying universities have no power to unilaterally declare all traditional academic work as Work for Hire: "The Copyright Act, however, explicitly requires that a transfer of copyright... If the faculty member is indeed the initial owner of copyright, then a unilateral institutional declaration cannot effect a transfer..." This section ends with the strongly worded overall assessment that "Such powers, so deeply inconsistent with fundamental principles of academic freedom, cannot rest with the institution."

Yes,@Timmy, that is the AAUP take on things -- not the universitys', or at least not every university (or the AAUP wouldn't need to make the statement, would they?).  I never said the "work for hire" policies were defensible, or right, but where they exist, they are real.  I think my description as "sticky" is accurate enough.

Like others, I see no problem with monetising lecture notes on your own website provided that students receive a non-monetised version.
Based on clarifications in the comments, I suspect the sticking point might be:

YouTube videos are a different matter; students are not required to watch them and are not informed about their existence.

Taking things that you have to produce anyway as part of your job, or at least are producing primarily for the benefit of the students, and monetising them on the side, is one thing. Creating extra material solely for the purpose of monetising it is quite different. If the professor was using work time (or even work equipment) to make these videos, that would be difficult to justify.

Buying books is anonymous. The professor does not see who buys his book.
Donating money could be perceived as bribery. I would never allow a student to pay for my coffee or buy me lunch. It would look unethical and feel plain wrong. The university might feel that the donation link is a similar case.
Personally, I would not ask for donations as a professor, as I would expect little income compared to much potential troubles.

Students had a dedicated download page: "He also had a version uploaded to the university's e-learning system, where students could download the PDF version without seeing the donation link." What the student does on the wide internet, should not be a matter of concern for the professor.

If the professor self-publishes the book and manages sales directly, they most likely will not be anonymous. Conversely, donating money through a ‘buy me a coffee’ link can be anonymous and/or aggregated data. In other words, there is no distinction of anonymity between the two scenarios: either can be anonymous or not.

Who is presumably bribing the professor? If a student wants to bribe their professor for good grades, they can do it whether or not they have a website distributing their material. And if the professor can be induced to falsify grades for the price of a cup of coffee, the university is obviously not paying them a reasonable wage.

This is wrong on two counts. There is no "bribery" involved as the students are specifically not asked to tip. A required textbook can be a problem if the professor doesn't deal somehow with the royalty issue, but that is not the case here. Read the original post. The "ask" is specifically directed at non-students and students are given all necessary materials. There is no coercion implied in the post.

Suppose a student finds the "tips" page and decides to contribute an outrageous amount, making their identity known. Then it is clearly a bribe but a professor can simply return it to the student with an admonishment. But that intent of soliciting bribes is nowhere in the original post.

@Buffy You are arguing wrong, because you are arguing reasonable and comparative. Comparativeness was clearly not involved when the professor was laid off because of his behavior.

"Buy me a coffee" is the name of the platform that facilitates authors (creators) to receive funding support from individual readers. The professor is not asking readers to literally buy him coffee. This can be better compared to a "pay-as-you-want" model for e-texts.

There’s no such thing as anonymous donations being bribery.

@Timmy It is less about the actual thing, but its potential perception as being questionable. I don't think it is an issue. Have you ever considered, other people with less knowledge regarding an online donation service might come to a different conclusion?

@usr1234567, That's a good point. Perhaps the university can state that while it doesn't break the ethical code, it creates enough confusion that some students may perceive it as an ethical violation, potentially harming the university's reputation. I still question if that's a sufficient reason to fire anyone. But that's an angle I didn't consider.
